# Plunker and Angular 2 child components don't display output

Tags: angularjs, typescript, output, plunker

I have the most basic angular 2 plunk but no errors are shown to give any indication of a problem.  Why can't I see any template output from the child components? Is this a Plunker Issue or is it me?

[Plunker version here with Index.html](https://plnkr.co/edit/tRWYEVMVKu1cduxfnNI3?p=info)

> PARENT: hello_world.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Jupiter} from './jupiter';
import {Uranus} from './uranus';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: `
  <p>Can you see jupiter?</p>
  <jupiter></jupiter>
  <p>Can you see Uranus?</p>
  <uranus></uranus>
`
})
export class HelloWorld {

}
```

> CHILD: jupiter.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'jupiter',
  template: `<p>Hello I'm Jupiter</p>`
})
export class Jupiter {}
```

> CHILD: uranus.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'uranus',
  template: `<p>Hello I'm Uranus Lol</p>`
})
export class Uranus {}
```

Comment: You are missing bootstrapping step and you don't have a module to contain your components. Please use my demo: https://embed.plnkr.co/L2lZa9/ to work on your example. It is also really simple.

Comment: Sid https://plnkr.co/edit/mJO07I?p=preview added based on yours but still no closer?

Comment: I've added a answer with new plnkr demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used my demo and used your code to get your expected results that you can see here: https://embed.plnkr.co/VKrvg4/

**SystemJS Bootstrap Process**

Basically, I've created a `main.ts` file that is used by SystemJS and then the code in this file bootstraps Angular with the help of `AppModule`.

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**Declaration**

This app module is responsible to declare the components that you would like to register in your Angular application using `declarations`.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './hello-world.component'
import { JupiterComponent } from './jupiter.component'
import { UranusComponent } from './uranus.component'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloWorldComponent, JupiterComponent, UranusComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Bootstrap**

The same module also uses `AppComponent` to `bootstrap` your Angular application in the code above. The component registered here will be rendered as parent component.

**Component Rendering Process**

When the app component is rendered, its template uses two other components. Now Angular is aware of your other components as it was registered using `declarations`.

```
import { Component }      from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: `
  <p>Can you see jupiter?</p>
  <jupiter></jupiter>
  <p>Can you see Uranus?</p>
  <uranus></uranus>
`
})
export class HelloWorldComponent {

}
```

You should be able to see your other component UI in view.

Comment: Thanks Sid, now I see!  I thought it was bootstrapped in the app.module.  Nooby issues :)